# How to modify HTTP response body with Charles Proxy rewrite tool and regex?

Tags: json, regex, http, charles-proxy

I'm trying to change HTTP response body with Charles Proxy using rewrite tool / regex? The response is a JSON.

So part of the returned response JSON body is:

```
"unavailablePosts": ["AA", "BB"],
```

and what I want is:

```
"unavailablePosts": "XXX",
```

I try to set up Charles' rewrite like this:

[image]

So the regex is like:

```
"unavailablePosts": \[(.*)\],
```

But ... (as I'm asking this question) it does not work, i.e. nothing is changed in response body.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? (IMHO, SO should not let post questions with this phrase.) You should say what it does not *match* and what it should *match*.

Comment: sorry, updated.

Comment: Perhaps, there are whitespaces in between, but only you can check that. Try `"unavailablePosts"\s*:\s*\[([\s\S]*?)\],`

Comment: with your regex it does not even work in "regex sandbox" like https://regex101.com/

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://regex101.com/r/2bY3dF/1)

Comment: Yep, you're right - it works.

Comment: Shall I post the solution? Does it work the way you expect on your end?

Comment: go ahead it works I'll accept :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127389/discussion-between-marian-pazdzioch-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe there are some linebreaks in between the values, and to match them you need to add `\s*` (zero or more whitespaces) around `:` and use `[\s\S]*?` (any 0+ chars but as few as possible as `*?` is a lazy quantifier) to match the substring between `[` and `],`:

```
 "unavailablePosts"\s*:\s*\[([\s\S]*?)\],
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. In this case Regex is `("unavailablePosts":)"[\s\S]*?"`
Value for replace is `$1"anything"`